# How to set flex ComboBox prompt property to empty string

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, mxml

Here is my code:

```
<mx:ComboBox  prompt="" editable="true" dataProvider="{tableSelector.list}"/>
```

When this code executes, flex just sets the selectedIndex to 0 and displays the first item in the dataProvider instead of leaving the text and prompt as the empty string "". How do I get around this? I need the text property to be "" unless the user selects another item in the combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this without modifying the dataProvider with this code:

```
combobox1.dataProvider = tableSelector.list;
combobox1.selectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend *not* using the mx ComboBox and use the Spark equivalent instead.  A way to fix this with the mx combobox would be to just use a space or use actionscript to set it because of the way mxml parses string info into properties.  An empty string is essentially equal to null in mxml.

I would question as to why you need an empty combobox to start with.  You might want to just use an empty item in the dataprovider instead.

Comment: Empty combobox might be required if you have an optional field that you want users to be able to 'reset' back to blank. There's no reason to recommend not using mx ComboBox, anyway--if it meets your needs. This isn't an unsolvable problem in Halo.

Answer (score 0):

+J_A_X answer, and check

```
requireSelection="false"
```

which is valid for Spark DropDownList ...